# Fetch a value every 10 minutes and store it inside a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, schedule

I have a function (let's call it "fetch_data_function") that returns a value that changes now and then. I want to store this value in a variable (let's call it "data_returned") that is inside a while loop once every 10 minutes.

If I put the function: schedule.every(1).minute.do(fetch_data_function) inside the while loop, it keeps starting again and again at every loop (obviously) and so the 10 minutes never pass.
If I put it outside the loop it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You have a while True loop, you would never reach the last line of your code, it would never be executed because the loop never ends. I suppose the `schedule.run_pending()` should also be inside the loop.

Also I don't know what is the full scope of your project, but you should be good with just doing this:

```
while True:
    data_returned = fetch_data_function()
    time.sleep(5) # get new values every 5 seconds
```